# Does Nexus 3 docker private registry support bearer authentication?

Tags: spinnaker, nexus3

I want to use nexus 3 as a private docker registry. All was ok until I tried to connect Spinnaker to this registry, and when the spinnaker is trying to connect to a registry with credentials I see this error:

```
2017-02-06T12:22:54.867681925Z 2017-02-06 12:22:54.867 ERROR 1 --- [0.0-7002-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver.docker.registry.api.v2.exception.DockerRegistryAuthenticationException: Failed to parse www-authenticate header: Docker registry must support 'Bearer' authentication.] with root cause
2017-02-06T12:22:54.867710980Z 
2017-02-06T12:22:54.867721497Z com.netflix.spinnaker.clouddriver.docker.registry.api.v2.exception.DockerRegistryAuthenticationException: Failed to parse www-authenticate header: Docker registry must support 'Bearer' authentication.
```

Does anybody know about this issue?

My clouddriver config:

```
    dockerRegistry:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
        - name: docker
          address: http://nexus.infrastructure:5000
          username: admin
          password: password
          email: admin@test.ru
          repositories:
```

Comment: did you figure out how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's strange, but it doesn't effect on functionality or 
I haven't seen it.

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov were you able to integrate spinnaker with Nexus3 repository ?